NEXT JS данные с API переданные в параметр функции другой страницы
Есть page.js который бывает в самом начале в папке app когда создаешь приложение в next.
В ней я через fetch погружаю данные с api и потом через карты они отображаются на главной странице.
Теперь я хочу чтобы при нажатии на карточку я мог заходить в новую страницу с подробным отображением данных продукта
Я создаю для этого папки movie/[id] и в ней файл page.jsx и в ней функция MoviePage
И ВОТ МОМЕНТ: В аргументы функции MoviePage передается {params}
Ну и дальше там опять fetch и в урле динамический параметр params.id
После return params.img params.title и так далее
Но функцию MoviePage я нигде не вызываю  и следовательно ничто я туда не передал
???Тогда как через params все вытягивается???
